# How to fix 'Defining a data frame'

Tags: r

Am trying to do some Multiple Stock Analysis, These stocks are Apple, Microsoft and Google. I have been able to import them from Yahoo Finance into R

I have tried the define code in other to define the day closing price of these stocks as a single variable. But I keep getting an error message.

```r
stocks <- as.xts(data.frame(AAPL = AAPL[, "AAPL.close"], GOOG = GOOG[, 
    "GOOG.close"], MSFT = MSFT[, "MSFT.Close"]))
#> Error in as.xts(data.frame(AAPL = AAPL[, "AAPL.close"], GOOG = GOOG[, : could not find function "as.xts"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Am expecting R to define the close price of the 3 stocks as 'Stocks' but all I get is this error message; 'Error in `[.xts`(AAPL, , "AAPL.close") : subscript out of bounds'

Comment: Have you loaded `xts` package `library(xts)`. the error suggests `could not find function "as.xts"`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. Yes I have loaded xts and still the same issue

Comment: Is it the same error `could not find function as.xts`

Comment: This is my coding in R and the exact error message immediately after the commando.   > library(xts)
> stocks <- as.xts(data.frame(AAPL = AAPL[, "AAPL.close"], GOOG = GOOG[, "GOOG.close"], MSFT = MSFT[, "MSFT.Close"])) 
Error in `[.xts`(AAPL, , "AAPL.close") : subscript out of bounds

Comment: ok, that is a different error.  Please check if all the datasett have the ssame index date or not.  Otherwise, may need a merge

Comment: Yes I've checked on that too and all looks good, but still the same error.